# Why Wont My FPS Go Above 60?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, recording

I am playing Minecraft 1.7.4 and just registered the full version of Bandicam.  Everything was fine until I noticed my FPS had dropped from an average of 200 to never going above 60.  I noticed Bandicam was still open so I switched it off and reset Minecraft but the FPS still averages 55 to 60 even on other worlds and servers.  I also tried restarting my computer and opening the game but that didn't do anything.  How can I fix this FPS problem?

Comment: just stabbing in the air but maybe your graphic card was set to vsync mode which forces fps that matches your monitor. this should be adjustable in the controlcenter (software) of the card

Comment: @Wandang  I don't think this is the issue because my fps was fine until installing bandicam

Comment: Do you have a 120Hz monitor? 60 FPS is exactly the right number of FPS you need otherwise.

Comment: I am not sure what monitor I have but my average FPS before getting Bandicam was 200

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bandicam should not be limiting your framerate while it is not in use. In Minecraft go to `Options` -> `Video settings` to make sure that `VSync` is "Off" and that `Max Framerate` is "Unlimited".

[image]

I doubt it will be having an effect if you're sure you've closed it, but you can also check the framerate limit in Bandicam in the FPS tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that the game is set to max performance mode in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a problem on Windows 8.  Windows is trying to make room for other programs.  Check if VSync is on and turn it **OFF**.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `fps_override 101` and `gl_vsync 0`.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off VSync and that will no longer limit your fps
 :)